# Spring giving 404 on loginProcessingUrl when authenticating login

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I've configured my Spring app to authenticate logins using the `/authenticate` url, but each time I try signing in it throws the following error:

`org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.noHandlerFound No mapping for POST /authenticate`

I'm confused because as far as I'm aware, the `loginProcessingUrl` should be allowing Spring to handle the authentication in the background without needing me to provide a URL.

Below are my `SecurityConfig`class

```
package com.eyanu.tournamentproject.config;

import com.myProject.tournamentproject.service.UserService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.WebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder encoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/", "/register**","/*.css", "/tournament**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .loginProcessingUrl("/authenticate")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .logout().permitAll();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/resources/**", "/static/**", "/static/css/**", "/js/**", "/images/**","/vendor/**","/fonts/**").anyRequest();
    }

    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(encoder());
        authenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(userService);

        return authenticationProvider;
    }

}
```

& the form which is trying to submit the login credentials

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Login</title>
</head>
<body>
<form:form action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/authenticate" method="POST">
    <p>
    Username: <input type="text" name="username">
    </p>
    <p>
    Password: <input type="password" name="password">
    </p>

    <input type="submit" value="Log in">

</form:form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see, the problem is in this line of code :

```
@Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/resources/**", "/static/**", "/static/css/**", "/js/**", "/images/**","/vendor/**","/fonts/**").anyRequest();
    }
```

remove `.anyRequest()`

**NOTE:** Ignore is a filter that complety bypasses Spring security, which is equivalent to not taking spring security.
So basically, URL requests which you set here `web.ignoring().antMatchers(URLs)` will be ignored by Spring Security , which means that these URLs will be vulnerable to CSRF, XSS, Clickjacking, etc. If you add `.anyRequst()` then all request will be ignored by Spring Security (including `"/authorize"`), and that's why you are getting 404

Comment: I'm using the Spring `form` tags for my form, which should handle CSRF automatically. I tried adding the hidden input above but it made no difference. I also tried disabling CSRF in my `SecurityConfig` class's `configure` method, but still no change.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I didn't noticed that. I updated my answer, It should work now.